# AWS IoT + SNS: Email not sending

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, amazon-sns, aws-iot

I'm following the AWS tutorial on how to [Configure and Test Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/config-and-test-rules.html). The only thing I'm doing differently is setting up an email rule (instead of SMS). I have successfully setup and subscribed to the SNS topic.

I've created a rule, and used the AWS IoT MQTT client to publish to a test topic that matched the rule. However no email is sent. How can I troubleshoot this?

The odd thing is I tried this same tutorial 3 days ago and it worked fine.

Comment: To troubleshoot enable IoT logs and then check the log to see what the error is. Check if the IAM role assigned to the rule has access to post to the SNS topic.